# React es6 slide menu only works one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I started with this code: https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/how-to-build-a-sliding-menu-using-react-js-and-less-css

But I'am using es6 and tried to convert the code. This is my result

```
    import Menu from "../components/layout/Menu";
    import MenuItem from "../components/layout/MenuItem";

    export default class Layout extends React.Component {   
    render() { 
    return (
            <Menu ref="right" alignment="right">
              <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
);
     }
    }
```

MenuItem

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    navigate(hash) {
        window.location.hash = hash;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menu-item" onClick={this.navigate.bind(this, this.props.hash)}>{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Menu

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
    };

    show() {
        this.setState({visible: true});
        document.addEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    hide() {
        this.setState({visible: false});
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menu">
                <div className={(this.state.visible ? "visible " : "") + this.props.alignment}>{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The menu opens when I click the button the first time. The menu closes if I click on the button a second time. But if I click on the button a third time nothing happens. The menu does not open and no error messages in the Chrome console. Can it be something with the EventListener? I get the same result if I comment out             `document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));`

Comment: When debuggin the third click, Are `showLeft()` or `showright()`from [App example](https://github.com/chrisharrington/demos/blob/gh-pages/react-controls/menu.html#L78) called?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is related but `Layout` should have a render() method that use `return(...)` to return the component.

Comment: I have that in my code, added it here now. Guess that if I missed return had the side not worked at all. The button works once now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
(render function in Menu):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {!!this.state.visible &&
        <div className={(this.state.visible ? "visible " : "") + this.props.alignment}>{this.props.children}</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

`!!this.state.visible &&` is like `if(this.state.visible === true)`

What this does is only render the menu if it's visible. It's a more 'reacty' way to do it to hide/show components (it unmounts & mounts all menu children). Otherwise, I'm guessing it may be an issue with the generated `visible` classname--for example, if `this.props.alignment` is undefined, or doesn't have a space, what string is being rendered? `visibleundefined`?, or if defined, does it need a space between `visible` and `alignment`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-side-bar. There are a complete example in [Example](https://github.com/mschez/react-side-bar/tree/develop/example) and looks fine.

`npm install --save react-side-bar`